# Is there a pattern to change compile behavior based on a type (proc macros)

Tags: rust, rust-proc-macros

I am trying to write a procedural macro that performs different behavior based on a trait type, which the macro may not have access to. For example, given the following trait:

```rust
trait Bar {
    type BarType;
}
```

I would like to be able to change macro behavior based on the chosen `BarType`, even when my macro may not have direct access to it:

```rust
// This macro sees nothing about BarType
#[macro_option_1]
struct Foo {}

// this macro sees nothing about BarType
macro_option_2!(Foo);

// This location works but is not desirable
// #[working_macro_option]
impl Bar for Foo {
    type BarType = Option<u32>;
}
```

A macro at `working_macro_option` would have access to `BarType`, but this location is not desirable (as my actual macro needs to work with multiple traits). So, my goal is to be able to use a macro that works at either `macro_option_1` or `macro_option_2`, which have no useful content available to parse.

I am hoping for a pattern along the lines of what `quote_spanned` makes possible ([link to example](https://docs.rs/quote/latest/quote/macro.quote_spanned.html#example)), but changing what the macro does in some way. So, I believe this needs to be something that's directly compilable, rather than something possible only in proc macros.

(this is unfortunately outside the scope of generics - my macro needs to create a function with a completely different signature based on type, for a C FFI)

---

Edit: more context on my end goal.

I am writing a library that helps users create a UDF, which is a dylib with a C interface. The `init`, `process`, `add`, `remove` etc. functions map nicely to traits (see my unfinished work [here](https://github.com/pluots/sql-udf/blob/fd5440d0f4e207498a2f92c0a3550395e4db17f4/udf/src/types/traits.rs)). My goal is that a user of my library can:

1. Define a struct or enum (which may be zero-sized, or contain something useful) which will give their UDF name
2. Implement my traits on this struct (one trait is required, the second is optional)
3. Add a `#[register]` macro to this struct

And from there, my library will generate the correct C interface functions via the macro. This isn't too different from how PyO3 works, I believe.

However, some of the C function signatures depend on the `Return` type within `BasicUdf`, so my macro needs some way to know what this is. I find it cleaner to put the macro on the main struct, so I am looking for a way to do this (hence this question)

My backup plan is to require placing the macro on the `impl`, which isn't terrible but is just less elegent (parsing the `Returns` type there is no problem). Something like a `PhantomData` marker on the main struct would also work, but I don't find that too ergonomic.

Comment: Quick thought: maybe my task is possible without proc macros to create a trait that specifies a function signature and implement it on acceptable types. Or, the same sort of thing but return a token stream that could be processed by the macro. Or, maybe something with `chalk` which I don't know much about. Much to test...

Comment: You can't access tokens outside the macros. Maybe if you'll expand on your actual use case we'll be able to help.

Comment: I know that any tokens outside the macro aren't visible, but I am hoping there is a pattern that I can add that allows for this and I am simply not aware of. Along the lines of the `quote_spanned` example of adding a struct with a `where` clause, that never would have occured to me. I added more context about the end goal, macro location is really just an ergonomics thing here